# Using Regex to remove anything within "<!--" and "/-->"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey guys, I have a string like this:

> Something useful (**less than sign**)!--?xml:namespace prefix = o ns =
>   "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
>   /--(**greater than sign**) Other useful stuff

I need to remove anything within the "". Is there an easy way to remove this using regex or a similar method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the **?** to prevent the Regex from eating more than necessary.

```
<!--.*?/-->
```

1. `<!--` as start tag
2. `.*?` cature anything - **non greedy**
3. `/-->` end tag

The main advantage of the solution is that it also works when you have multiple comment tags in your code.

`test<!-- test /-->test /-->` will result in `testtest /-->`

`A<!-- comment/--> is a<!-- comment/-->!` will result in `A is a!`

Comment: Damn you're good. Ok I have another one: I need to remove all new lines within <li> </li>. Any ideas?

Comment: parsing "<li>.*?(?<</li>)</li>" - Invalid group name: Group names must begin with a word character.  - Also just wanted to clarify that I'm trying to remove any "\n". This regex stuff looks like jibberish to me so I'm not sure if it's doing that.

Comment: @Rob <li>.*?</li> is actually enough. @JonB - good point removed step 3 because the **?** was enough.

Comment: That's removing everything inside the <li> </li>. I only need to remove any newline characters (\n). Or better yet any non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think **Regex.Replace(yourtext, @"`<!--.*-->`","")** can do the trick.
**yourtext** is the string you want to check.

Comment: kees' solution seems better, after some tests, I realized my solution doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Jep... your solution 'eats' to much. That's always the problem of Regex ;-). Regex is one greedy bastard :D

Comment: Indeed, I'm currently learning Regex through "Mastering Regular expressions" and I'm often discouraged. But what a lovely tool when you know how to use it.

Comment: @Louhike... I've got an awesome tool for you!! One of the MS people made this program: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/RegexWorkbench. It has the option to interpret your regex and assist you in building it.

Comment: Thanks ! This will help me a lot.